# Google Data Studio Community Connector: Passing Token Through Embed URL Not Working

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm struggling to get a community connector to work for a web-app I'm building.

I wrote a very basic connector in App Script to do row level filtering on an embedded dashboard, using these docs Google provides: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/viewers-cred-with-3p-credentials

My connector uses getConfig() and getData() to pass a token into an API endpoint, and that API endpoint returns data specific to that user.

The connector works perfectly when I pass in a token in the GUI by modifying the configuration, but doesn't work when I try to pass in the token using the embedded url.

#### Example 1

User Token = `5wKu4QLvc9PC7tkPyg`

**Steps:**

1. Click "Edit connection"
2. Enter token in input field [which is generated by getConfig() in app script]
3. Click "Reconnect"
4. Click "Apply" on dialogue box that comes up
5. Google Data Studio **correctly retrieves 3 rows of data** for this token

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### Example 2

User Token = `z6ps6Vhb9hzB333gG4`

**Steps:**

1. Click "Edit connection"
2. Enter token in input field [which is generated by getConfig() in app script]
3. Click "Reconnect"
4. Click "Apply" on dialogue box that comes up
5. Google Data Studio **correctly retrieves 1 row of data** for this token

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### The primary issue

When I use the embed URL for the dashboard, I noticed the App Script execution logs aren't showing that **getConfig** or **getData** operations are being run.

The end result is the token doesn't appear to be passed into the embed URL at all.  The data remains the same as in the GUI-based report.

However I can tell the embed URL is being invoked, because it does call **getAuthType** in the App Script execution logs, see image below.  (I made the change in the GUI at 9:50:59 PM, and then the subsequent timestamps are me attempting to hit the embed URL)

[image: Google App Script Logs]

#### Sample

Here's the sample of the actual embed URL I'm using:
https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/9dea8b8a-5b51-4add-adb2-afda3861b241/page/VXkvC?config=%22%7B%5C%22token%5C%22:%20%5C%22z6ps6Vhb9hzB333gG4%5C%E2%80%9D%7D%E2%80%9D

Per the Example 2 above, the token being used in this embed URL should only return 1 row of data, but it's returning all 3.

I followed the Google docs, which suggest this is the format to use: `https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/[report_id_here]/page/[page_id_here]?config="{\"token\": \"[token_here]\”}”`

I'm wondering if it's possible the Google docs are incorrect (or) out of date and my embed url is malformed?  I can't get my head around this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Resolution

1. Despite being part of the `getConfig()`, apparently you also have to "Add a Parameter" for the token to your Data Source on the report.  This will result in the parameter being visible under all fields.
2. Next, go to Resource > "Manage report url parameters" and check the box for "Allow to be modified in report URL".  Take note of the "Name" field.  Mine was `ds0.token`
3. Finally, use this URL syntax: `https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/[report_id_here]/page/[page_id_here]?params=%7B"[name_from_step_2]":"[value]"%7D`

Which for me translated into:
`https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/9dea8b8a-5b51-4add-adb2-afda3861b241/page/VXkvC?params=%7B"ds0.token":"12345"%7D`

Which in raw URL format looks like:
[https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/9dea8b8a-5b51-4add-adb2-afda3861b241/page/VXkvC?params=%7B"ds0.token":"12345"%7D](https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/9dea8b8a-5b51-4add-adb2-afda3861b241/page/VXkvC?params=%7B%22ds0.token%22:%2212345%22%7D)

One additional observation.  I was watching the logs on my API endpoint, and I noticed Google caches any data it brings back from the endpoint. So don't be surprised if you don't see a `getData()` call in your App Script execution logs for any tokens you've already passed.  Just make up a new token to see a new getData execution log.